# wp_ajax return 0 what is my mistake?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

this is my function

```
function multi_delete(){

    echo ':D';

    die();
}
```

my add acction

```
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_delete','multi_delete');
```

And js code

```
jQuery('#ckta_products_admin').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:           "POST",
        url:            '/admin-ajax.php?action=multi_delete',
        data:           jQuery(this).serialize(),
        dataType:       "json",
        success:        function(data){if(data==1){
            location.reload(true);
        }}
    });

});
```

Response is "**0**". I'm administrator and nopriv is not necessary. Other ajax calls work but not this one. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper json format.

```
function multi_delete(){

    echo json_encode(array(
      'success' => true
    ));

    die();
}
```

---

```
jQuery('#ckta_products_admin').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:           "POST",
        url:            '/admin-ajax.php?action=multi_delete',
        data:           jQuery(this).serialize(),
        dataType:       "json",
        success:        function(data){
          if(data.success){
            location.reload(true);
          }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I try but return 0, anyway.

Comment: If you are using Chrome, look at the request and response in the Network inspector. Is the server actually sending '0'?

Comment: exactly , comparing with other ajax the request is the same, only this function returns 0 .

(sorry , I translate with google )

Comment: I found the solution, jQuery(this).serialize(), do not know why but when spread with: jQuery (this) .find ('input: checked'). serialize () worked.

Answer (score 1):

You've set the datatype to "json", but you're returning a non-json string, so probably when jQuery tries to unserialize it, it's failing and setting it to "null". Maybe try with some valid JSON:

```
function multi_delete(){

    echo '{"test": ":D"}';

    die();
}
```

Comment: I try and not work, return 0 anyway, wtf happens u.u

Comment: I would suggest using `json_encode` combined with an `array` argument rather than bulding json strings

Comment: is a plugin :D, I found the solution, jQuery(this).serialize(), do not know why but when spread with: "jQuery (this) .find ('input: checked'). serialize ()" ignore why but worked.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your

```
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_delete','multi_delete');
```

in plugin main file or in WordPress theme `functions.php` file?

Comment: is a plugin :D, I found the solution, jQuery(this).serialize(), do not know why but when spread with: "jQuery (this) .find ('input: checked'). serialize ()" ignore why but worked.